# How to get this budget constraint?

Tags: consumer-theory

I have an Euler equation $ (\frac{ c_ {t+1} }{c_t})^\sigma = \beta (1+r)$,where $c_t$ is the t period consumption,r is interest rate and $\beta$ is discount rate, and a budget constraint $\sum _{t=0}^\infty \frac{c_t}{(1+r)^t}=\sum _{t=0}^\infty \frac{y_t}{(1+r)^t}$, where $y_t$ is income.

My question is how to substitute Euler equation into budget constraint to get the following equation?

$c_t\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{[\beta(1+r)]^\frac{j}{\sigma}}{(1+r)^j}=\sum _{t=0}^\infty \frac{y_t}{(1+r)^t}$

Answer (score 1):

The hint is to use the recursive Euler equation to express all future consumptions $c_{t+j}$ as a function of current consumption $c_t$, and to play with the indexes in the sum of the left.

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Separate the consumption time periods
$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{ c_ {t+1} }{c_t}\right)^\sigma & = \beta (1+r) \\
\frac{ c_ {t+1} }{c_t} & = \left[\beta (1+r) \right]^\frac{1}{\sigma} \\
c_ {t+1}  & = c_t \left[\beta (1+r) \right]^\frac{1}{\sigma} \\
\end{align}$$

Notice that $(\frac{ c_ {t+2} }{c_{t+1}})^\sigma = \beta (1+r)$. So,

$$c_ {t+2}  = c_{t+1} \left[\beta (1+r) \right]^\frac{1}{\sigma} = c_{t} \left[\beta (1+r) \right]^{\frac{1}{\sigma} \cdot 2}$$

So

$$\sum _{t=0}^\infty \frac{c_t}{(1+r)^t}$$

can be expressed as a geometric series and simplified. Working that out for yourself should give you the desired answer.

Comment: How did you get the 3rd equation from the 2nd one?

Comment: I made a mistake. I'll amend the solution.

Comment: Following your hint, I can get $\sum _{t=0}^\infty \frac{c_t}{(1+r)^t}=c_t\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{[\beta(1+r)]^\frac{j}{\sigma}}{(1+r)^j}$.  This is calculate the PV of consumption flow. LHS start from period 0 to $\infty$,while RHS,$\sum _{j=0}^\infty \frac{c_{t+j}}{(1+r)^j}$, from period t to $\infty$. I am confuse about this.

Comment: I don't *think* there's any meaningful distinction between $j$ and $t$. Just different ways to denote time.

Comment: I mean that starting from period 0 and from t (Say t=9).